# Why does my ceiling fan change direction 2 or 3 times before it finally stays in one direction?

Tags: ceiling, ceiling-fan

When I turn my ceiling fan on it will reverse direction several times until it settles into the correct direction.

Answer (score 10):

It's probably an optical illusion. The ["wagon wheel effect"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wagon-wheel_effect)

You are probably viewing it in light produced by a fluorescent lamp rather than an incandescent lamp.

There do exist electric motors that can work in either direction but no motor will speed up then stop and start working in the reverse direction all by itself.

Answer (score 2):

You probably have a DC motor fan. The DC motor uses magnets so it has to align before starting this is why you see it moving back and forth before it starts. The DC motor also uses 70% less energy than a AC motor and will most likely last much longer too.

Answer (score 2):

Because there is no back EMF at zero speed, therefore motor has to start its rotation in a random direction. Once there is back EMF to be detected, then comes the direction to be assessed whether it is correct or incorrect. If rotation is in the reverse direction, the motor will stop and start rotating in the forward direction, otherwise, it will keep moving in the same direction. And it is all done through the software program.

Answer (score 0):

Your forward, reverse switch may be defective causing it to go back and forth. Maybe try taking the switch and jogging it back and forth and see if this helps.